# Divs com cores alternando

Tags: jquery

Tenho um ajax que mostra os resultados pra mim em um JSON, preciso que as cores da `<div>` alternem: na primeira cor cinza, na segunda branca, na terceira cinza, na quarta branca e assim em diante. Como faço isso? Posso botar a classe 1 na div par e a classe 2 na div impar, só preciso saber como fazer.

Segue meu código com exemplo em html:

```html
<div class="historico_registroA">
    <span class="historico_registro_data">12/10/2016 às 11:00</span>
</div>
<div class="historico_registroB">
    <span class="historico_registro_data">22/11/2016 às 15:30</span>
</div>
<div class="historico_registroA">
    <span class="historico_registro_data">07/12/2016 às 18:00</span>
</div>
<div class="historico_registroB">
    <span class="historico_registro_data">09/12/2016 às 15:00</span>
</div>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_dom_addclass

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em `css` acho que seria mais fácil, você está tentando fazer a famosa lista zebra não é mesmo? (me corrija se estiver errado).

```
suaClasse:nth-child(even) { background: #CCC; }
suaClasse:nth-child(odd) { background: #FFF; }
```

Comment: é isso mesmo, me ajudou muito, vlw!